# Using FutureBuilder in main.dart

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Below code always show OnboardingScreen a little time (maybe miliseconds), after that display MyHomePage. I am sure that you all understand what i try to do. I am using FutureBuilder to check getString method has data. Whats my fault ? Or any other best way for this ?

```
saveString() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('firstOpen', '1');
}
```

getString() method always return string.

```
getString() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String txt = prefs.getString('firstOpen');
  return txt;
}
```

main.dart

```
home: new FutureBuilder(
            future: getString(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return MyHomePage();
              } else {
                return OnboardingScreen();
              }
            })
```

Comment: i found the solution. [One time splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50655196/1928396)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually I'm using another route, rather than FutureBuilder. Because futurebuilder every hot reload will reset the futureBuilder.

There always will be some delay before the data loads, so you need to show something before the data will load.

Snapshot.hasData is showing only the return data of the resolved future.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

const isOnboardingFinished = 'isOnboardingFinished';

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  Timer timer;
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _checkIfFirstOpen();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _checkIfFirstOpen() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var hasOpened = prefs.getBool(isOnboardingFinished) ?? false;

    if (hasOpened) {
      _changePage();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  _changePage() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      // this is route builder without any animation
      PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) => HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isLoading ? Container() : OnBoarding();
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text('homePage'));
  }
}

class OnBoarding extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<void> handleClose(BuildContext context) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool(isOnboardingFinished, true);
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => handleClose(context),
          child: Text('finish on bording and never show again'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code always open homepage. How about onboarding screen ?

Answer (score 2):

From the [FutureBuilder class documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html):

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

So you need to create a new Stateful widget to store this Future's as a State. With this state you can check which page to show. As suggested, you can start the future in the initState method:

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {

  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
final Future<String> storedFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
      super.initState();
      storedFuture = getString();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
            future: storedFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return MyHomePage();
              } else {
                return OnboardingScreen();
              }
            });
  }
}
```

So in your home property you can call it FirstPage:

```
home: FirstPage(),
```

Your mistake was calling `getString()` from within the build method, which would restart the async call everytime the screen gets rebuilt.