# Screen is getting build first and then the state is getting emitted

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

What I am trying to do is get the local app info from the state if the user is not authenticated and route him appropriately. I am getting the data from Hive.
Cubit code

```
@injectable
class LocalAppInfoCubit extends Cubit<LocalAppInfoState> {
  final UserRepository _userRepository;
  LocalAppInfoCubit(this._userRepository)
      : super(const LocalAppInfoState(null, null));

  Future<void> getLocalAppInfo() async {
    var result = await _userRepository.getLocalAppInfo();
    result.fold((l) {
      emit(LocalAppInfoState(null, l));
    }, (r) {
      emit(LocalAppInfoState(r, null));
    });
  }

  void updateLocalAppInfo(LocalAppInfo localAppInfo) {
    _userRepository.updateLocalAppInfo(localAppInfo: localAppInfo);
    emit(LocalAppInfoState(localAppInfo, null));
  }
}
```

Splash Screen Code

```
if (state is UnauthenticatedState) {
            final localAppInfoState = context.read<LocalAppInfoCubit>().state;
            if (localAppInfoState.localAppInfo != null) {
              if (localAppInfoState.localAppInfo!.hisVisited) {
                //checking it the user is visiting first time
                context.pushRoute(const LoginRoute());
              } else {
                context.pushRoute(const OnboardingMainRoute());
              }
            } else if (localAppInfoState.appError != null) {
              print("error");
            } else {
              print("null");
            }
          }
```

I am calling getLocalAppInfo() in the main. It is getting null value because initial state has null values. For now, I am just printing. I have also tried calling it in initState.How do I deal with it?
Tried using Future builder.

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: context.read<AuthCubit>().getAuthState(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data is AuthenticatedState) {
              // context.pushRoute(const HomeRoute());
              return Center(
                child: Text("auth"),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.data is UnauthenticatedState) {
              // final localAppInfoState = context.read<LocalAppInfoCubit>().state;
              // if (localAppInfoState.localAppInfo != null) {
              //   if (localAppInfoState.localAppInfo!.hisVisited) {
              //     //checking it the user is visiting first time
              //     context.pushRoute(const LoginRoute());
              //   } else {
              //     context.pushRoute(const OnboardingMainRoute());
              //   }
              // }
              return Center(
                child: Text("Unauth"),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: Text("Null"),
              );
            }
          }
          return Center(
            child: Text("Error"),
          );
        },
      ),
```

I also added a function to auth cubit

```
 Future<AuthState> getAuthState() async {
    var result = await _userRepository.getUserInfo();
    late UserInfo? userInfo;

    result.fold((l) {
      return AuthErrorState(l);
    }, (r) async {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(
          seconds:
              1)); //the listner is not working without this.Have to correct it
      userInfo = r;
      if (userInfo == null) {
        return const UnauthenticatedState();
      } else if (userInfo!.isAuthenticated) {
        return const AuthenticatedState();
      } else {
        return const UnauthenticatedState();
      }
    });
    return const UnauthenticatedState();
  }
}
```

Comment: try using `FutureBuilder` where you can pass `getLocalAppInfo` as future, then check for `snapshot.connectionState` and `snapshot.hasData` to show appropriate screen based on data or no data .... https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: should we use routes in the build?

Comment: no you can supply the widget directly... the build invocation will be the first route...  The page on the route will be determined by FutureBuilder....

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I didn't understand what you said. I tried using Future Builder but the route is not working in it when I return a widget it works. I will edit the code.

Comment: does it solve the issue?

Comment: No, I can't change the route. I commented route part and tried. The state is getting recognized correctly but the route is not working in it.

Comment: Maybe this will help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66219875/18645340